# Prisma database schema for multi-level SaaS application

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, prisma

I'd just like to get some feedback on my current database schema and a few issues I'm having with it.

I'm trying to create multi-level `User -> Organisation -> Project` account flow, one that you would usually find in a SaaS application.

I'd like a system where:

1. A User can have and belong to many organisations
2. An `Organisation` can have many projects
3. A `Project` can have many users (but only users that belong to the given organisation).

I think I've created mostly what I'm after, with the exception of #3. Should the database enforce this type of relationship? Or is this just something that should be handled with code when querying? Eg. When attempting to add a `User` to a `Project`, first check whether that `User` is part of the `Organisation`?

Here is the diagram:
[image]

Here is my current Prisma schema:
Note: I've used an explicit `m-n` relation for `UserOrganisation` so I can add more fields later.

```
model User {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  email     String @unique
  firstName String
  lastName  String

  password Password?

  organisations UserOrganisation[]
  projects      Project[]
}

model Password {
  hash String

  userId String @unique
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
}

model UserOrganisation {
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())

  userId String
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)

  organisationId String
  organisation   Organisation @relation(fields: [organisationId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)

  @@id([userId, organisationId])
  @@unique([userId, organisationId])
}

model Organisation {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  name     String
  users    UserOrganisation[]
  projects Project[]
}

model Project {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())

  name String

  users User[]

  organisationId String
  organisation   Organisation @relation(fields: [organisationId], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!